# ionic failed on android device with firebase

Tags: android, ionic-framework, firebase

i am trying to add fire-base to my ionic project.
i added the JavaScript files

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.3/angularfire.min.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

and then added the `firebase` dependency to my app

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','firebase','starter.controllers'])
```

Now, in the browser everything is fine.

But when i run the app on android device - it stuck on the splash screen.

If i remove the `firebase` dependency everything is working great.

What could be the problem.

p.s i am using all the latest versions of ionic and so...

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what is your error when you run on android, but I had a similar problem, and the solution was add a tag to configure whitelist access from your app in your `index.html`. my code looks like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src * &apos;unsafe-eval&apos;; connect-src * &apos;unsafe-eval&apos;; object-src &apos;self&apos;; style-src * &apos;unsafe-inline&apos;; img-src * 'self' data:">
```

if you want to know about whitelist plugin, you can use the oficial documentation [Plugin whiteList](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) and review content security polices.